# Spacing being messed up in regular expression

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression

```
var string_regex=(\s*[\{\[]?\%?[\s]*)[\@A-Za-z1-9_\.\s\+\-\*\\]*([\s\*]*=[\s\*\$]*[\{\"]?)[\@A-Za-z1-9_\.\s\+\-\*\\]*(\s*[\}\"]?)([\}\]\%\s]*)
```

where the `[\@A-Za-z1-9_\.\s\+\-\*\\]*` will eventually be replaced by a string in my program that gets written out to a file that utilizes `$1, $2, $3 and $4` as follows:

```
val newLineToBeReplacedOrAdded = "$1" + "set type cookies" + "$2" + "sugar cookies" + "$3" + "$4"
```

The string I'm testing it on is

```
{% set type cookies = "sugar cookies" %}
```

which it properly matches. However, the issue I'm having is that when I write it out to the file, the spacing isn't preserved next to the equals sign so I end up with

```
{% set type cookies= "sugar cookies" %}
```

It's a very minor difference but I'd appreciate feedback on how to improve the expression further to prevent this.

[Here is a link to the regex!](https://regex101.com/r/yN4mX0/1)

I believe its an issue specifically with `[\@A-Za-z1-9_\.\s\+\-\*\\]*`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Made it non-greedy match on space before =.

```
[\@A-Za-z1-9_\.\s\+\-\*\\]*?
```

https://regex101.com/r/yN4mX0/3

Comment: Thank you! I learned something new with the non greedy match :) And thank you for pointing out where the problem is. It should help others too

Comment: @vks - according to the capture group, they would want to include those asterisks.  So it is technically valid for the example.

Answer (score 3):

```
(\s*[\{\[]?\%?[\s]*)[\@A-Za-z1-9_\.\s\+\-\*\\]*[^\s]([\s\*]*=[\s\*\$]*[\{\"]?)[\@A-Za-z1-9_\.\s\+\-\*\\]*(\s*[\}\"]?)([\}\]\%\s]*)

                                                 ^^
```

You will have to ask previous group to not consume that space .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yN4mX0/2

or if you have `lookbehind` use

```
(\s*[\{\[]?\%?[\s]*)[\@A-Za-z1-9_\.\s\+\-\*\\]*(?<!\s)([\s\*]*=[\s\*\$]*[\{\"]?)[\@A-Za-z1-9_\.\s\+\-\*\\]*(\s*[\}\"]?)([\}\]\%\s]*)

                                                 ^^
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/yN4mX0/4

Comment: Wow that was fast and what a fantastic answer! Thank you!

Comment: `[^\s]` gives another meaning to the regex. See [\S](https://regex101.com/r/yN4mX0/7) vs [(?<!\s)](https://regex101.com/r/yN4mX0/8)

Comment: @Jonny5 yeah hurry spoiled the curry :P